# Tarskian and model-theoretic account of validity. ( On the importance of " logical form" in the account of deductive validity).

Tags: logic, soft-question

- In a paper published in A. Varzi's *Nature of Logic*, and entitled " Validity" , Graham Priest claims that the model-theoretic account of validity and the tarskian one are basically different ( though the tarskian one may be considered as a particular case of the MT one).

Source : in the 1999 section of the publication list ( http://grahampriest.net/publications/papers/) , section 1.4 of Priest's paper.

- As far as I understand , the tarskian one relies on the notion of valid form ( what you get when you replace all the non-logical vocabulary by variables while leaving logical constants in place).

Is this tentamount to claiming that the model theoretic notion of validity makes no official use of the notion of logical form?

Note : Model-theoretically , a reasoning " $\Gamma$ therefore $\phi$ " is valid just in case  any possible model  of $\Gamma$ ( i. e. structure in which all the members of $\Gamma$ are true) is also a model of $\phi$.

- Most introductory and elementary  textbooks say that a reasoning is valid iff its form is valid , that is iff every possible instance of its logical structure is valid.

Does this mean that they are committed to a tarskian account of validity rather to a model theoretic one?

More generally can one still say that, in the standard model theoretic account of validity, the logical consequence relation is formal ( in such a way that the conclusion holds " *vi formae*" ?

Comment: Useful [Tarski’s Truth Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/) for an introduction to the 1933 and the 1956 definitions.

Comment: See [The 1956 definition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/#195DefOff): "In 1933 Tarski assumed that the formal languages that he was dealing with had two kinds of symbol (apart from punctuation), namely constants and variables. The constants included logical constants, but also any other terms of fixed meaning. The variables had no independent meaning and were simply part of the apparatus of quantification. "

Comment: Model theory by contrast works with three levels of symbol. There are the logical constants (=,¬, &), the variables (as before), and between these a middle group of symbols which have no fixed meaning but get a meaning through being applied to a particular structure. The symbols of this middle group include the nonlogical constants of the language, such as relation symbols, function symbols and constant individual symbols. They also include the quantifier symbols,since we need to refer to the structure to see what set they range over.This type of three-level language corresponds to math usage"